# How to show gadget for certain categories labels in blogger and not for other posts?

Tags: html

Is this possible to show gadget for specific post..
Suppose there are 100 posts in my blog and i want 1 gadget to display only when specific 20 posts are open.
And that gadgets should not appear for remaining post which don't have the said label.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean exactly with gadget? Do you mean showing a badge or an icon on the page only after the user have clicked on all the posts with a given label?

Comment: A gadget or Widget is like Page Tab in a website or a Contact form or a HTML Frame